# Holding on my thread is misunderstanding

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123815/how-to-calculate-arcsine-with-standard-adroid-calculator-4-4-2

I am not looking for mathematical formula but some kind of combination how to count arcsine. I found a way, but I feel that it must exist some easier way, some kind of combination which let a user to obtain the result much faster, so this problem is not a question about numerical methods but using built-in application ([calculator](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator) and [application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) are in the list). I've asked the crew for help but the only answer was :

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting us. Generally, if you have a question about a site, the best place to ask is on Meta, the site for questions and issues about the main site. Stack Exchange is collaboratively built, maintained, and moderated by the community. Asking on meta will help others learn about these issues so they are not repeated in the future.
>
> Please let us know if you need anything further.
>
> Regards,
> The Stack Overflow Team

So can anybody help with this simple problem?

Comment: "How to use the limited set of operations provided by a particular app to calculate arcsin" is a math question.  Everything you just described is about math.  If you want a calculator app with more operations then you should use one.

Comment: @MatthewRead no Matthew you are mistaken. My question was at last bit unclear - anyway the users were able to answer it, isn't it nice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned on [Matthew's comment](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/holding-on-my-thread-is-misunderstanding#comment4580_2013),

> "How to use the limited set of operations provided by a particular app to calculate arcsin" is a math question. Everything you just described is about math. If you want a calculator app with more operations then you should use one.

Basically, the issues are:

- You can't find arcsine function in stock calculator
- You know the alternative way to calculate it, but you want the simpler one

The first question is a legit question and actually answerable (answer: there's no operator to do that, install 3rd-party calculator instead).

However, you dragged our attention to the second question, which is unclear and off-topic:

- Unclear, because you don't explain what do you mean by "*a simpler way*" (do you want the formula? Or setting a macro to calculate that? Or what? What is the device model and available operators in your calculator?).
- Off-topic, if you really meant to ask the math formula (we are not the specialists in maths, did you mean to ask it on [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) instead?).

Comment: "...What is the device model and available operators in your calculator?..."  - I would gladly make a screen and show it but I don't know how, so I can tell that the only data about aforementioned built-in calculator is: Calculator version 4.4.2-v5B5K-0 , my device is "Orange Rise 30" , alias "Alcatel  Pixi 3 (4)" with Android 4.4.2 KitKat. The answer  to my question is that the operator arc sine is not a part of the application, but its very strange for me.I meet such a situation first in my life , if we are talking about built-in application like calculator.